# Can't install xamarin on visual studio

Tags: xamarin

I've problem in installing xamarin on visual studio 2013 it close when the started launch?!?

It say unhandled exception and visual studio restart.

Comment: contact support@xamarin.com, or post on forums.xamarin.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about installation issue and this can be found in their official site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running the installer as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly not relevant in your case, but you should also realize that you need to have a "Business" level license of Xamarin to run the Visual Studio tools.  Look at the pricing matrix here:

https://store.xamarin.com/

I ran a 30-day free trial of Xamarin business and was able to integrate in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.